# runnibg tftp command on Ubuntu

Tags: embedded-linux, xilinx, busybox, tftp

So i have one embedded platform Zedboard upon which i am able to run the Xilinx Linux.Also in mine board i have enabled the wifi interface and also i have busybox application in mine root file system and when i typd the command

busybox

it shows the msg

BusyBox v1.22.1 (2016-11-01 12:04:21 GMT) multi-call binary.

Now i have one Ubuntu PC. From this Ubuntu PC i can ping mine Zedboard. 
 Could somebody tell me how to transfer some file form Ubuntu PC to this   embedded platform Zedboard using tftp protocol step by step as well as necessary settings that need be enabled prior to the communication in the Ubuntu PC.

Regards

Aditya

Answer (score 0):

I think [This](https://mohammadthalif.wordpress.com/2010/03/05/installing-and-testing-tftpd-in-ubuntudebian/) link will help you. I used this tutorial to setup the TFTP server and successfully worked with loading binary files to Beagleboneblack with U-boot bootloader over TFTP from my host PC.

Comment: That link is very helpful. It seems that i have to access the files from the Zedboard terminal which is on the Ubuntu PC.But i want in reverse manner i.e from mine Ubuntu PC terminal  I want to push the files to mine Zedboard. Could u suggest something..

Comment: Well i haven't tested this scenario but you can use the 'put' after connecting the with the board, you can check the documentation of tftp command. I will check if this works and will get back.

Comment: Actually in mine zedboard when i am typing tftp at mine prompt then it is giving me the following option:-                                                           tftp:[option] [host] [port]       Now in that tutorial we are not doing like this. i do not know what is correct. i will also check it and update u.

Comment: It did not work. Because on mine zedboard there is no tftd ,so i think i need to run the tftd in mine zedboard, then only i can transfer the file from ubuntu to zedborad.